# SharedPreferences для сохранения состояния

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Я отлично понимаю как сохранить таким образом текст. Но как сохранить состояние
управляющих элементов? Я хочу чтобы RadioButton, CheckBox, и ToggleButton. Оставляли свое сохраниение, когда я закрываю приложение. Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CheckBox checkBox;
    private static final String PREFS_FILE = "Account";
    private static final String PREF_CHECK_BOX = "CheckBox";
    private static final String PREF_TOGGLE_BUTTON = "TOGGLE_BUTTON";
    private static final String PREF_RADIO_BUTTON = "RADIO";
    //приложению требуется сохранять небольшие кусочки данных для дальнейшего использования, например,
    // данные о пользователе, настройки конфигурации и т.д.
    // Для этого в Android существует концепция Preferences или настройки.
    // Настройки представляют собой группу пар ключ-значение, которые используются приложением.
    SharedPreferences settings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void onClickCheckBox(View view) {
        if(((CheckBox)view).isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Отмечен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            /*SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_CHECK_BOX, true);
            editor.apply();*/
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Не отмечено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onClickToggleButton(View view) {
        if(((ToggleButton)view).isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Отмечен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Не отмечено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onClickRadioRabbit(View view) {
        if(((RadioButton)view).isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Выбран:" + ((RadioButton) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Не отмечено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onClickRadioDog(View view) {
        if(((RadioButton)view).isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Выбран:" + ((RadioButton) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Не отмечено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onClickRadioCat(View view) {
        if(((RadioButton)view).isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Выбран:" + ((RadioButton) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Не отмечено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Мой код на данный момент.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Вы при изменении состояния виджета судя по коду пытаетесь сохранить данные в память. Это правильное решение, просто дальше в методе `onCreate` вам нужно менять состояние виджета в зависимости от того что вы сохранили. Например этот кусок кода у вас хотя и закомментирован, но вполне нормальный:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean(PREF_CHECK_BOX, true);
editor.apply();
```

таким образом в памяти устройства у вас сохраняется состояние кнопки. Я бы предложил для начала параметризовать это значение таким образом:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean(PREF_CHECK_BOX, ((CheckBox)view).isChecked());
editor.apply();
```

дальше вам нужно считать данные

```
settings.getBoolean(PREF_CHECK_BOX,false) // <----- тут false это значение по-умолчанию
```

это нужно делать уже после присвоения значения переменной `settings` и `checkBox`:

```
settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
checkBox.setChecked(settings.getBoolean(PREF_CHECK_BOX,false));
```

это например с чекбоксом. Так же можно сделать и с остальными виджетами. Там где будет радиокнопка можно для начала переместить все кнопки в радиогруппу, например так:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioKb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/kb1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="Onscreen - ABC" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#33000000" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/kb2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="Onscreen - Qwerty" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#33000000" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/kb3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="Standard softkey" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#33000000" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/kb4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="Physical keyboard" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#33000000" />

</RadioGroup>
```

выше это просто пример, чтобы вы понимали как работать с таким виджетом. То есть не нужно делать три отдельно стоящие кнопки, их можно сложить в один контейнер. Дальше вы после получения этого виджета так же как и чекбокса устанавливаете значение для ранее выбранной кнопки:

```
((RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(index)).setChecked(true);
```

где index это значение которое вы сохранили. Более подробно про radioGroup можно почитать [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/radiobutton.php) а про сохранение данных в SharedPreferences [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php).